# box2dweb raycast

Tags: javascript, box2d

I am trying to get the distance between my character and the ground, I have found something that looks like it should do what I want but it has been written for another version of box2d.

Original:

```
float targetHeight = 3;
float springConstant = 100;

//make the ray at least as long as the target distance
b2Vec2 startOfRay = m_hovercarBody->GetPosition();
b2Vec2 endOfRay = m_hovercarBody->GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,-5) );

overcarRayCastClosestCallback callback;
m_world->RayCast(&callback, startOfRay, endOfRay);

if ( callback.m_hit ) {
    float distanceAboveGround = (startOfRay - callback.m_point).Length();

    //dont do anything if too far above ground
    if ( distanceAboveGround < targetHeight ) {
        float distanceAwayFromTargetHeight = targetHeight - distanceAboveGround;
        m_hovercarBody->ApplyForce( b2Vec2(0,springConstant*distanceAwayFromTargetHeight),
        m_hovercarBody->GetWorldCenter() );
    }
}
```

I have tried to change it to what I think it should be but it doesn't even call the callback.

```
var targetHeight = 3;
var springConstant = 100;

//make the ray at least as long as the target distance
startOfRay = new b2Vec2(m_hovercarBody.GetPosition());
endOfRay = new b2Vec(m_hovercarBody.GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,-5)));

function callback(raycast){
    if ( raycast.m_hit ) {
        var distanceAboveGround = (startOfRay - raycast.m_point).Length();

        //dont do anything if too far above ground
        if ( distanceAboveGround < targetHeight ) {
            var distanceAwayFromTargetHeight = targetHeight - distanceAboveGround;
            m_hovercarBody.ApplyForce( b2Vec2(0,springConstant*distanceAwayFromTargetHeight),
        m_hovercarBody.GetWorldCenter() );
        }
    }
}
m_world.RayCast(callback, startOfRay, endOfRay);
```

Any idea how to convert it to work with box2dweb?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the original bit of code was written for a platform where the coordinate system works differently.

In a Canvas element, the coordinate system starts from the top left corner, meaning that `m_hovercarBody.GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,-5))` is checking for a point above the character, rather than below.

I'm not sure about the rest of the code but try changing that to `m_hovercarBody.GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,5))` and see what happens.

EDIT:

I think actually the problem is with the way you've structured your callback. Looking up the reference for the Raycast function would [reveal more](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.html#RayCast%28%29).
(The Javascript version of Box2D you're using is an automatic port of the Actionscript one. Given the two have fairly similar syntax, you can use the [reference for Flash](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/).)

The original code you posted seems to be C++, but I don't know much about its syntax. It seems there's some sort of class that does the raycasting (`overcarRayCastClosestCallback`). You can either look for that, or try and build your own callback function according to the first link I posted. It would be something along the lines of:

```
function customRaycastCallback(fixture, normal, fraction) {
// you can, for instance, check if fixture belongs to the ground
// or something else, then handle things accordingly

    if( /* fixture belongs to ground */ ) {
        // you've got the fraction of the original length of the raycast!
        // you can use this to determine the distance
        // between the character and the ground
        return fraction;
    }
    else {
        // continue looking
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried lots of different coordinates, that was just an example. I don't think it matters that the coordinates are negative or not as my world spans a greater area than shown on the canvas. It's not calling the callback function at all which is the main problem. I'm not convinced I have converted the code properly but I can't see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: The problem is in your callback function - check the edit I just made.

Comment: It still wasn't calling the callback for some reason so I just created my own startOfRay and endOfRay using GetWorldCenter() instead and that seemed to get it working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try running this on your browser. I coded this when I was learning sensor and RAYCAST in Box2Dweb. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Box2dWeb Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="420" style="background-color:#333333;" ></canvas>
      <div id="cc" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:100px; width:500px; height:50px; margin:0;"></div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var    b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
        ,      b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef
        ,      b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body
        ,      b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef
        ,      b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World
        ,      b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape
        ,      b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape    
        ,      b2ContactFilter = Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactFilter
        ,      b2MouseJointDef =  Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2MouseJointDef
        ,      b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw
        ,      b2Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture
        ,      b2AABB = Box2D.Collision.b2AABB
        ,      b2WorldManifold = Box2D.Collision.b2WorldManifold
        ,      b2ManifoldPoint = Box2D.Collision.b2ManifoldPoint
        ,      b2RayCastInput = Box2D.Collision.b2RayCastInput
        ,      b2RayCastOutput = Box2D.Collision.b2RayCastOutput
        ,      b2Color = Box2D.Common.b2Color;

        var world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0,10), true);
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');


        //box

        var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.Set(9,7);
        bodyDef.userData = 'box';

        var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
        fixDef.filter.categoryBits = 1;

        fixDef.density = 10.0;
        fixDef.friction = 0.5;
        fixDef.restitution = .5;

        fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
        fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(1,5);

        var box1 = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
        box1.CreateFixture(fixDef);

        //circle

        var bodyDef2 = new b2BodyDef;
        bodyDef2.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef2.position.Set(4,8);
        bodyDef2.userData = 'obj';

        var fixDef2 = new b2FixtureDef;
        fixDef2.filter.categoryBits = 2;
        fixDef2.filter.maskBits = 13;
        fixDef2.density = 10.0;
        fixDef2.friction = 0.5;
        fixDef2.restitution = .2; 
        fixDef2.shape = new b2CircleShape(1);
        //circlesensor
        var cc = new b2FixtureDef;
        cc.shape = new b2CircleShape(2);
        cc.shape.SetLocalPosition(new b2Vec2(0 ,0));
        cc.density = 0;
        cc.isSensor = true;
        cc.filter.categoryBits = 8;

        var wheel = world.CreateBody(bodyDef2);
        wheel.CreateFixture(fixDef2);
        wheel.CreateFixture(cc);

         //create a ground

         var holderDef = new b2BodyDef;
         holderDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
         holderDef.userData = "ground";
         holderDef.position.Set(10, 14);

         var fd = new b2FixtureDef;
         fd.filter.categoryBits = 4;
         fd.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
         fd.shape.SetAsBox(10,1);

         var ground = world.CreateBody(holderDef);
         ground.CreateFixture(fd);



         //create another static body
         var holderDef = new b2BodyDef;
         holderDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
         holderDef.position.Set(10, 20);
         var temp = world.CreateBody(holderDef);
         temp.CreateFixture(fd);

         var c=0;
         $(window).keydown(function(e) {
             $('#aa').html(++c);
             code = e.keyCode;
             if(c==1)   {
             if(code == 38 && onground)
                 wheel.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0,-10));
             if(code == 39)
                wheel.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(1000,0), box1.GetWorldPoint(new b2Vec2(0,0)));
             if(code == 37)
                wheel.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(-1000,0), box1.GetWorldPoint(new b2Vec2(0,0)));
             }
         });
         $(window).keyup(function(e) {
            c=0;
         });

         var listener = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
         listener.BeginContact = function(contact) {
             if(contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData()== 'obj' || contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData()== 'obj' ) // think about why we don't use fixture's userData directly.
                onground = true;// don't put 'var' here!
             fxA=contact.GetFixtureA();
             fxB=contact.GetFixtureB();
             sA=fxA.IsSensor();
             sB=fxB.IsSensor();
             if((sA && !sB) || (sB && !sA)) {
                 if(sA) {
                     $('#cc').prepend(contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData() + ' is in the viscinity of body '+contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData()+'<br>');
                 }
                 else   {
                     $('#cc').prepend(contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData() + ' is in the viscinity of body '+contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData()+'<br>');
                 }
             }
         }       
         listener.EndContact = function(contact) {
         if (contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData()== 'obj' || contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetUserData()== 'obj' )
             onground = false;
         }   


        var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
        debugDraw.SetSprite ( document.getElementById ("canvas").getContext ("2d"));
        debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30);     //define scale
        debugDraw.SetAlpha(1);
        debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(.3);    //define transparency
        debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
        debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
        world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

        window.setInterval(update,1000/60);

        //mouse

        var mouseX, mouseY, mousePVec, isMouseDown, selectedBody, mouseJoint;
        var canvasPosition = getElementPosition(document.getElementById("canvas"));

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
           isMouseDown = true;
           handleMouseMove(e);
           document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, true);
        }, true);

        document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
           document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, true);
           isMouseDown = false;
           mouseX = undefined;
           mouseY = undefined;
        }, true);

        function handleMouseMove(e) {
           mouseX = (e.clientX - canvasPosition.x) / 30;
           mouseY = (e.clientY - canvasPosition.y) / 30;
        };

        function getBodyAtMouse() {
           mousePVec = new b2Vec2(mouseX, mouseY);
           var aabb = new b2AABB();
           aabb.lowerBound.Set(mouseX - 0.001, mouseY - 0.001);
           aabb.upperBound.Set(mouseX + 0.001, mouseY + 0.001);

           // Query the world for overlapping shapes.

           selectedBody = null;
           world.QueryAABB(getBodyCB, aabb);
           return selectedBody;
        }

        function getBodyCB(fixture) {
           if(fixture.GetBody().GetType() != b2Body.b2_staticBody) {
              if(fixture.GetShape().TestPoint(fixture.GetBody().GetTransform(), mousePVec)) {
                 selectedBody = fixture.GetBody();
                 return false;
              }
           }
           return true;
        }

         //at global scope
        var currentRayAngle = 0;
        var input = new b2RayCastInput();
        var output = new b2RayCastOutput();
        var b = new b2BodyDef();
        var f = new b2FixtureDef();
        var closestFraction = 1;
        var intersectionNormal = new b2Vec2(0,0);
        var intersectionPoint = new b2Vec2();
        rayLength = 25; //long enough to hit the walls
        var p1 = new b2Vec2( 11, 7 ); //center of scene
        var p2 = new b2Vec2();
        var normalEnd = new b2Vec2();
        function update() {

            if(isMouseDown && (!mouseJoint)) {
                        var body = getBodyAtMouse();
                        if(body) {
                           var md = new b2MouseJointDef();
                           md.bodyA = world.GetGroundBody();
                           md.bodyB = body;
                           md.target.Set(mouseX, mouseY);
                           md.collideConnected = true;
                           md.maxForce = 300.0 * body.GetMass();
                           mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(md);
                           body.SetAwake(true);
                        }
                     }

                     if(mouseJoint) {
                        if(isMouseDown) {
                           mouseJoint.SetTarget(new b2Vec2(mouseX, mouseY));
                        } else {
                           world.DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
                           mouseJoint = null;
                        }
                     }

            world.Step(1 / 60, 10, 10);
            world.DrawDebugData();
            world.ClearForces();
            world.SetContactListener(listener);
            ray();

        };
        function ray()  {

            //in Step() function
            var k = 360/20;
            var t = k/60;
            var DEGTORAD = Math.PI/180;
            currentRayAngle += t * DEGTORAD; //one revolution every 20 seconds
            //console.log(currentRayAngle*(180/Math.PI));

            //calculate points of ray
            p2.x = p1.x + rayLength * Math.sin(currentRayAngle);
            p2.y = p1.y + rayLength * Math.cos(currentRayAngle);

            input.p1 = p1;
            input.p2 = p2;
            input.maxFraction = 1;
            closestFraction = 1;

            var b = new b2BodyDef();
            var f = new b2FixtureDef();
            for(b = world.GetBodyList(); b; b = b.GetNext())    {           
                for(f = b.GetFixtureList(); f; f = f.GetNext()) {
                    if(!f.RayCast(output, input))
                        continue;
                    else if(output.fraction < closestFraction)  {
                        closestFraction = output.fraction;
                                    intersectionNormal = output.normal;
                    }
                }

            }
            intersectionPoint.x = p1.x + closestFraction * (p2.x - p1.x);
            intersectionPoint.y = p1.y + closestFraction * (p2.y - p1.y);

            normalEnd.x = intersectionPoint.x + intersectionNormal.x;
            normalEnd.y = intersectionPoint.y + intersectionNormal.y;

            context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

            context.beginPath(); // Start the path
            context.moveTo(p1.x*30,p1.y*30); // Set the path origin
            context.lineTo(intersectionPoint.x*30, intersectionPoint.y*30); // Set the path destination
            context.closePath(); // Close the path
            context.stroke();

            context.beginPath(); // Start the path
            context.moveTo(intersectionPoint.x*30, intersectionPoint.y*30); // Set the path origin
            context.lineTo(normalEnd.x*30, normalEnd.y*30); // Set the path destination
            context.closePath(); // Close the path
            context.stroke(); // Outline the path
        }
        //helpers

         //http://js-tut.aardon.de/js-tut/tutorial/position.html
         function getElementPosition(element) {
            var elem=element, tagname="", x=0, y=0;

            while((typeof(elem) == "object") && (typeof(elem.tagName) != "undefined")) {
               y += elem.offsetTop;
               x += elem.offsetLeft;
               tagname = elem.tagName.toUpperCase();

               if(tagname == "BODY")
                  elem=0;

               if(typeof(elem) == "object") {
                  if(typeof(elem.offsetParent) == "object")
                     elem = elem.offsetParent;
               }
            }

            return {x: x, y: y};
         }


   </script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Raycast in Box2dWeb that I got working:

```
 var p1 = new b2Vec2(body.GetPosition().x, body.GetPosition().y); //center of scene
 var p2 = new b2Vec2(body.GetPosition().x, body.GetPosition().y + 5); //center of scene
 world.RayCast(function(x){ 
    console.log("You've got something under you");       
 }, p1,p2);
```